# Qt How can I use DocumentsLocation

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qstandardpaths

I am trying to develop an application with Qt. My problem is: I need to write and delete something in a text file. I am writing the text file as full path, the path on my computer. If the application runs on another computer, it will not find this path. I found out that I can use QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation for its solution. But I couldn't figure out how to use it. Can you teach me or give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Documents location by below code:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStandardPaths>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qDebug() << QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DocumentsLocation);
    return app.exec();
}
```

This code prints current user's Documents Location. You can store this folder location in QString and then use it as you need to store your files.

Reference: [QStandardPaths::StandardLocation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html)